# .htaccess rule for redirecting /node?page=31 to the main page of the site

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to find a redirect rule for .htaccess which would redirect

`/node?page=31` or `/node` or `/node?page=1` or `/node/`

but not

`/node/291` and not `node/291/edit` because these are handled differently (see below)

to the main page of my site (let's say `www.example.com`)

I have one rule dealing with `/node/xxx` below

`RewriteRule ^(../)?node/([0-9]+)$ noderedirect.php?nid=$2 [L]`

but I need to find the rules for `/node?page` and I can't figure out how to do them.

can anyone help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(page=(31|1))?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^node/?$ /? [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: Will that not affect the other code that redirects node/xxx types of pages to my custom .php script? Thanks!

Comment: No it won't since it is only matching `node/?$` in regex